# Como reproducir videos seguidos en html 5

Tags: html, html5

Tengo una lista de video que vienen de una BD en un vector, como reproduzco del primero al último sin repetir uno a uno los videos?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos llegan desde un json y son asignados a la lista "videos", al momento de reproducir el primero video llamo a la función addEventListener, y me reproduce el siguiente video, el error lo tengo en el último video. La posición se encuentra fuera, como detengo el reproductor luego de reproducir el último video?

```
    function ReproducirVideoCambioDireccionPoretiquera1(res) {
            var count = Object.keys(res).length;
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                videos[i] = res[i].direccionweb;
            }
            var reproductor = document.getElementById("mivideo")
            reproductor.src = videos[0];
            document.getElementById("mivideo").play();
            contador = 0;
            reproductor.addEventListener("ended", function ()
            {
                    ++contador;
                        reproductor.src = videos[contador];
                        document.getElementById("mivideo").load();
                        document.getElementById('mivideo').play();
                  
             }, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Recuerda que debes editar _tu pregunta_. Esto es una _no-respuesta_.

Comment: Debes ir al apartado de **Editar** que se encuentra al final de tu pregunta, ahí podrás, agregar, quitar, modificar elementos que hallas omitido desde que formulaste la pregunta, evita hacerlo en el área de respuestas.